# oracle trigger throws ora-04098

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Seeking some basic help, probably a typo in code.

I have the following:

```
create table scott.original(mystr varchar2(10))
insert into scott.original values('hi')
select * from scott.original

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER scott.original_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON scott.original
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    select 'deleting or updating' from dual
END;
/

insert into scott.original values('bye')
```

There insert of 'bye' throws error ora-04098, I can't see an issue in oracle, granted first time I'm trying to create a trigger in oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any `SELECT` statement in a PL/SQL block needs to select the data `INTO` some variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER scott.original_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON scott.original
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    l_variable VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    select 'deleting or updating' 
      into l_variable
      from dual
END;
/
```

will be valid syntax.  Of course, this trigger isn't actually doing anything but I assume that's something you're planning on addressing later.

Comment: Thank you, yes I was trying to make a simple trigger before putting all the logic into it.  works great now